# Open two .vimrc at startup in vim?

Tags: vim

Is it posible to source two .vimrc in vim from command line?

Suppose I have ~/.vimrc. I want to create an alias that sources .vimrc as well as another arbitrary vim configuration file, but only when starting vim. Something like:

```
alias vim='vim --source=~/.vimrc2"
```

I dont want to call this file from .vimrc itself calling source command, I want to know if it's possible to call it when starting vim as a parameter or something.

(I thought about placing a .vimrc in /etc as well.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
vim -S ~/.vimrc2
```

as found [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Command_line_switch_to_source_a_script)